# OrientDB - create document with subquery and relationship

Tags: orientdb

I'm new to OrientDB and I'm developing a test application for internal use (orientdb 2.2.17).

I'm trying to add a new document to class with a subquery as one of the values.

**Classes:**

```
CREATE CLASS Website
CREATE PROPERTY Website.id String
CREATE PROPERTY Website.name String
CREATE PROPERTY Website.created DateTime

CREATE CLASS User
CREATE PROPERTY UserEndpoint.id String
CREATE PROPERTY UserEndpoint.website String 
CREATE PROPERTY UserEndpoint.created DateTime
```

I'm trying to add a new user with a reference to some website.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Website (name) VALUES ('localhost:8090')
```

And after that to add user:

```
INSERT INTO User (website) VALUES (SELECT id FROM Website WHERE )
OR
INSERT INTO User (website) VALUES (SELECT @rid FROM Website WHERE )
```

The results are not what I'm expecting, the `User.website` parameter is a string that represents an array, instead of a string that represents a single value.

```
 {
     "result": [
         {
             "@type": "d",
             "@rid": "#30:0",
             "@version": 1,
             "@class": "User",
             "created": "2017-12-28T16:35:31",
             "id": "a9816adc-8808-4673-b5a7-b11493b0ce36",
             "website": "[Website#25:0{created:Thu Dec 28 16:34:25 UTC 2017,id:e0ce0e68-003b-4a01-8c4f-856d9eeb6125,name:localhost:56} v1]"
         }
     ]
     "notification": "..." }
```

Expected:

```
 {
     "result": [
         {
             "@type": "d",
             "@rid": "#30:0",
             "@version": 1,
             "@class": "User",
             "created": "2017-12-28T16:35:31",
             "id": "a9816adc-8808-4673-b5a7-b11493b0ce36",
             "website": "#25:0"
         }
     ]
     "notification": "..." }
```

And I also want to make a relationship between website and users (user belong to one website and website might have a lot of users), is this is the right way:

```
CREATE LINK websiteUsers TYPE LINKSET FROM User.website TO Website.rid
```

?

And while I query for a user and I want to get website details, did the add automatically to result?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the `website` property as a link, not as a string:

```
 CREATE PROPERTY UserEndpoint.website LINK Website
```

This will result in an actual link that you can query.

As an alternative, you can replace the link with an edge (graph model)

```
 CREATE CLASS Website EXTENDS V
 CREATE CLASS User EXTENDS V
 CREATE CLASS HasWebsite EXTENDS E

 INSERT INTO User (name) VALUES ('foo')
 INSERT INTO Website (name) VALUES ('localhost:8090')
 CREATE EDGE HasWebsite FROM (SELECT FROM User WHERE name = 'foo') TO (SELECT FROM Website WHERE name = 'localhost:8090')
```

And then query it as follows:

```
 get the website for a user:

 SELECT expand(out("HasWebsite")) FROM User WHERE name = ?
```